# What is the gnome keyring api for PyGi?

Tags: python, introspection, gobject, pygobject

Does anyone where I can find the gnome keyring api in PyGi?

I used to do:

```
import gnomekeyring
```

Now I want to use the new python/gobject introspection so it would be something like:

```
from gi.repository import GnomeKeyring
```

But I can't find the module to load. Does someone know if/how I can access the Gnome Keyring api with python gobject introspection?

Answer (score 4):

To access the Secret Service (gnome-keyring) you should use the libsecret (new library replacing libgnome-keyring)

It has [builtin](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libsecret/tree/libsecret/Makefile.am#n123) support for Gobject Introspection so this should work:

```
from gi.repository import Secret
```

Answer (score 0):

PyGI still under development and adaption so it still doesn't have any official documentation or API reference. Every time I need to try something with PyGI I check the [C Gnome Development Reference](http://developer.gnome.org/references) there you can find the C documentation for [gnome-keyring](http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-keyring/stable/). It seems to be very similar to the old gnomekeyring.